# Why the extra space is coming to my screen?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

How to adjust name and username text according to the text the username and name text is coming on top of profileimage and just messing up the styling how can i fix this problem and make text on there location and adjust according for example instagram no matter how long is username it adjust the fond according how can i do with my code? this is how it look like https://ibb.co/vYvQRW2

For example Linkdin if you visit any profile the name text is so fit no matter how long or small it is how to do that?

I tried using a package called "react-native-responsive-fontsize" but it didn't work in that also I created three different styles for texts for example small medium and large but its was also not works as expected

i also try is using the numberOfLines and ellipsizeMode props of the Text component in React Native didint work

```
<View style={styles.container}>
<StatusBar />
<BottomNavigation navigation={navigation} page={'profile'} />
<TopNavigation navigation={navigation} page={'profile'} />
{userdata ? (
  <FlashList
    data={userdata.posts}
    numColumns={3}
    getItemCount={() => userdata.posts.length}
    getItem={(data, index) => data[index]}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    initialNumToRender={10}
    windowSize={10}
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
    removeClippedSubviews={true}
    updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
    estimatedItemSize={100}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
      <FastImage
        style={styles.PostImage}
        key={index}
        source={{ uri: item.post }}
      />
    )}
    ListHeaderComponent={
      <>
        <View style={styles.section1}>
            {
              userdata.profileImg ?
                <FastImage style={styles.profileimg} source={{ uri: userdata.profileImg }} />
                :
                <FastImage style={styles.profileimg} source={{ uri: 'https://instagram.fjai2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/44884218_345707102882519_2446069589734326272_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fjai2-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=-L25Q8dbzSkAX9HYQTU&edm=AJgCAUABAAAA&ccb=7-5&ig_cache_key=YW5vbnltb3VzX3Byb2ZpbGVfcGlj.2-ccb7-5&oh=00_AfB8CuKyW_AZ5Y4F6SBkOpjOurIgUPwwnsRxj4LEGpSNqw&oe=6436BCCF&_nc_sid=cda0c5' }} />
            }
          <Text style={styles.nameText}>dwadawdawddsawdawddwada</Text>
          <Text style={styles.usernameText}>@dwadadsdwadawdaddddwad</Text>
        </View>
      </>
    }
  />
) : (
  <ActivityIndicator color="white" size="large" />
)}
</View>

import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { scale, verticalScale, textScale, moderateScale } from './responsiveSize';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const profileImgSize = scale(100);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    paddingBottom: verticalScale(80)
  },
  section1: {
    width: width / -2,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  profileimg: {
    width: profileImgSize,
    height: profileImgSize,
    borderRadius: profileImgSize / 2,
    // margin: moderateScale(10),
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginRight: 250,
    marginTop: 60
  },
  nameText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: textScale(25),
    borderRadius: 20,
    top: -100,
    right: 15
  },
  usernameText: {
    color: 'gray',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: textScale(18),
    borderRadius: 20,
    top: -90,
    right: 20
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    marginBottom: verticalScale(20),
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  PostImage: {
    width: width / 3 - 10,
    height: width / 3 - 10,
    margin: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});

export default styles;
```